# How to push an empty array into a non-empty array that contains a list of objects?

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular7

I want to push an empty array into a non-empty array that contains a list of objects.

```
organise() {
        this.array = [];
        this.current.suggested.forEach((value: any, key: any) => {
            console.log(value);
            if (value.type === 'Major') {
                value.array = [];
                this.array.push(value);
                console.log(this.array);
            }
        });
}
```

I need to add the empty-array array in the value.

Comment: The array is empty... so what do you expect after "pushing it" into value? Also you want to add it into `value` or `value.array`?

Comment: Because in the next step, I want to push in to value.array.So I want to add this array[] into value.

Comment: What does your original data look like? You are iterating using forEach which suggests an array, but then you are specifying 'key' which only exists on objects. Can you include a sample of this.current.suggested

Comment: Also include an example of what you want the final result to look like in the end. Currently there is no reason the above code shouldn't work, so I think you need to communicate the problem more clearly

Comment: { id:1, title: "Welcome", response: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken."}

Comment: I am expecting an output like- { id:1, title: "Welcome", response: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.", array: [ ]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would look like,

```
this.array.push(Object.assign({}, value, { array: [] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is not an array, then you cannot `push` something into it; you just set it: `value.array=[]`.
Then, you can `push` values into  `value.array`.

In case the array is not empty beforehand, the same thing applies. So ultimately, you can use a code like the one below:

```
if(value.array===undefined){
    value.array = [];
}
value.array.push(someVal);
```

Comment: An error is occurring in the line value.array = [], saying that cannot add property array, the object is not extensible.